# ModalPopupExtender Animations OnShown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am learning ASP .NET and came across modal popup extender. I found that animations are possible with modal popup but I have a question as to what is the difference between OnShowing and OnShown tags. A google search gave me

```
OnShowing – Called before the modal popup is shown.
OnShown – Called after the modal popup is shown.
OnHiding – Called before the modal popup is hidden.
OnHidden – Called after the modal popup is hidden.
```

But, I am confused about something. When I click on the target button and use OnShowing, there is no animation effect. But when I use OnShown, the animation is successful. Now, isn't the OnShowing called BEFORE the modal popup is shown, so when I Click on the target button, it is the function OnShowing which is supposed to be called. I think I am missing something here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: it is something like weather html is loaded or not. OnShowing menas it started the event but not html is created.And onshown means html has been created. An similarly for the other two event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked this [AnimationExtender with ModalPopup] (http://forums.asp.net/p/1318051/2624063.aspx#2624063) ? They provided a really nice sample for ModalPopUpExtender Animations. It will give you a true understanding on your concern.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning true by adding `return true;` on onshowing function